# Python, why is the dataclass attribute read-only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass which its signature gets updated based on the active configs before it gets initiated and may be modified after initiation. Accordingly, I have something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(slots=True, frozen=False)
class MyClass:
    att_1: str = field(init=False)
    att_2: str = field(init=False)

    @classmethod
    def update_class(cls, first, second):
        cls.att_1 = first
        cls.att_2 = second
```

My problem is that although the dataclass is not frozen, when I initiate the class I cannot change the attributes anymore. This is a sample of what I do.

```
MyClass.update_class("11", "12")
print(MyClass.att_1)
a = MyClass()

print(a)
print(MyClass.att_2)
print(MyClass.att_1)
a.att_2 = "002"
print(a)
```

Running this I get what is shown bellow:

```
11
MyClass(att_1='11', att_2='12')
12
11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/b.py", line 25, in <module>
    a.att_2 = "002"
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object attribute 'att_2' is read-only
```

Can someone tell me why is `att_2` read-only and how can I fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to *achieve* by `update_class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is that you are using `__slots__` and then removing the `__slots__` descriptors, breaking your class. So, consider (without the `dataclass` involved):

```
>>> class Foo:
...     __slots__ = "x", "y"
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.x = 1
>>> foo.x
1
>>> Foo.x
<member 'x' of 'Foo' objects>
>>> Foo.x = None
>>> foo.x
>>> foo.x = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object attribute 'x' is read-only
```

So, one *simple* solution is to not use `__slots__`, but it really isn't clear to me how this is all supposed to work or why you have an `update_class` method (and what it's supposed to accomplish).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to have to read on __slots__. But to answer your question, the application has hundreds of configs which are set when the service starts. I wanted to create a way for all the modules to access the configs without the need to pass around an instance nor to create redundant instances of the configs class as not all the modules are initiated from the same place. So either redundant instances of configs have to get created and be passed along different pipelines, or a globally accessible object has to exist. This seems like a good solution and is pretty fast.

Comment: @m.m frankly, global mutable state is a pretty classic anti-pattern that you should avoid. In any case, you probably should just use a *regular class* for this, there really is no point to use a `@dataclass` with slots. You can probably just use the class definition with class attributes and call it a day

Comment: But what is the better approach then? Having multiple instances of the same object is also an anti-pattern and has a lager impact on the performance. This is to some extent an attempt to replicate Java's encapsulation as well.

Comment: What do you mean "java's encapsualtion"? And why would you need to create multiple instances of the same object? Just use the same object. It really isn't clear to me the exact problem you are encountering.

Comment: @m.m so, " I wanted to create a way for all the modules to access the configs without the need to pass around an instance nor to create redundant instances of the configs class as not all the modules are initiated from the same place." what does that mean exactly? Can you edit your question and elaborate and add an example maybe?

Comment: Honestly, it would be a little off topic for the question but when I change the signature of the class at the very beginning of starting the service, I can just import it from then on and use it without the need to initiate it. So I would use `from MyModule import Configs` and just use it as `Configs.config_1`. Any module can import it, the updates are accessible by all modules, I can program it to block specific updates, it doesn't need to be initiated, it needs to be set only once, and it is fast and more so if I can use slots. But if you have a better solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: @m.m What you are saying doesn't make sense, what do you mean by "signature". In any case, initializing a single class that would act as a configuration container is fine.As long as you don't mutate the global state outside of initialization, it isn't an anti-pattern. `__slots__` is marginally faster, but then you *do need an instance* which is what the answer I have is explaining (why you cannot mix `__slots__` with updating class variable, `__slots__` applies to *instance* variables, when you update the class variable, you remove the `__slots__` descriptors that allow you to use them!)

Comment: By signature I mean the definition of what is accepted and returned. Most of the elements of the config are objects or functions themselves. But they come together based on a lot of factors. Initializing a single class would be useful for a single pipeline only. That is why I don't want to rely on that. Otherwise I have to keep initializing redundant instances per each call and per each pipeline. Which is slower than what I am doing now. I am also trying to squeeze as much performance out of it as I can. But I understood the point about `__slots__`. Thanks for your help.